# Is there any action in wordpress that points above of posts?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm Trying to write a wordpress plugin but i cannot find an action or Way to point above of posts

Comment: Do you want to add content before post content?

Answer (score 0):

Try  this:(in `functions.php`)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'featured_image_before_content' ); 

 function featured_image_before_content( $content ) { 
   /* if ( is_singular('post') && has_post_thumbnail()) { */


        $content = 'YOUR DATA'. $content;

    /*  }*/

    return $content;
}
```

you can add condition from here:[LINK](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/conditional-tags/)